# Is this the first mention of Stack Overflow in the mainstream media?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Stack Overflow got a mention in the Guardian's Ask Jack column for 2nd July.

http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2009/jul/02/delphi7-windows-vista

**NOTE:** *I'm still not sure of the etiquette for this sort of thing here on MSO. I know it would get closed straight away over on SO, but I'm hoping we can be a bit more flexible here.*

**UPDATE:** The other links are interesting, but I was thinking about primarily non-programming related media. I get the impression that the sort of people who write into "Ask Jack" aren't particularly computer or Internet savvy so they aren't likely to come across Stack Overflow directly or via the blogs etc. mentioned by others.

Comment: I think that's exactly the sort of things to post here!

Comment: Yea, we should talk about ourselves as much as we can :D

Comment: I phrased it as a question just in case ;)

Comment: not sure a small blog post on the guardian counts as mainstream :P

Comment: It's printed in the paper too (admittedly in the technology pages)

Comment: I do think this is the very place to put stuff like this - especially as it was one of my questions published ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Here are some more news / reviews by large sites I found

- [Google Blogoscoped: StackOverflow's Karma Bounty, Data Dump, and Sister Sites](http://www.newsfactor.com/blog_article.php?aid=2176180&full_skip=1)
- [You’ve Got Questions. That’s Understandable.](http://androidguys.com/?p=5738)
- [Stackoverflow.com to Deliver Programming Expertise](http://www.eweek.com/c/a/Application-Development/Stackoverflowcom-to-Deliver-Programming-Expertise/)

Answer (score 3):

Scoble was a *big* one, early on (and thanks to [Michael Krakovskiy](http://www.deadprogrammer.com/) for mentioning it to him)

[PR-less launch kicks off a stack overflow of praise](http://scobleizer.com/pr-less-launch-kicks-off-a-stack-overflow-of-praise/)

Also, Shoes links to us, which is quite an honor:

http://help.shoooes.net/

I'm sure there are others I can't think of right now..

Comment: The Guardian is a big paper in the UK..

Answer (score 3):

Joel Spolsky sometimes mentions the site in his Inc. Magazine column, and he wrote a whole column about how Stack Overflow got started:

[How Hard Could It Be?: The Unproven Path](http://www.inc.com/magazine/20081101/how-hard-could-it-be-the-unproven-path.html).

Comment: right, duh! geez. Should have remembered that.

Answer (score 2):

From [The Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk):

2008: [100 top sites for the year ahead](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2008/dec/18/internet-websites) (under Geek Squad)
2009: [The 100 essential websites](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2009/dec/09/best-websites-internet)

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff got another name check in the Guardian in this week's [technology section](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/gamesblog/2009/jul/15/games-evony-spam-internet). It's interesting to see this sort of crossover from blogging back to the mainstream. I think it just means that blogging is becoming the mainstream.

Answer (score 1):

Also adding Heise.de, one of Germany's most renowned IT news sites and publishers of the c't magazine:

[Stack Overflow: Community-Site will Antworten auf Programmierfehler geben](http://www.heise.de/developer/meldung/Stack-Overflow-Community-Site-will-Antworten-auf-Programmierfehler-geben-219569.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you counting blogs belonging to mainstream media in the mix?

If so, 26 May 2009, Articulate, the ***arts*** blog outlet of the ABC (aka Aunty), mentions the [image encoding in 140 characters or less](http://blogs.abc.net.au/articulate/2009/05/mona-lisa-mosai.html) challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned in High Scalability Blog:

http://highscalability.com/stack-overflow-architecture

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/high-scalability-blog-on-stack-overflow/